# On Java Controller how to get the value of annotation @RequestMapping("/getThisValueFromOtherClass")?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On Java MVC Controller how to get the value of annotation @RequestMapping("/getThisValueFromOtherClass")? I know we can extract this by using java reflections but is there any other way? Thank you.

```
@RequestMapping("/getThisString")
public class MyController{}
```

Comment: just to be clear, u want to get the value attribute of @ReqestMapping annotstion defined in controller A from some other class ? Also may I know whats the use case ?

Comment: @coder - I would like to get the value of the annotation, the purpose if for tracking changes of the url, for example im referencing this url from other class, instead of editing it on all places i would just get the value of the mapping like this MyController.getBaseMapping(). I know we could get it by java reflections but is there other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose is just to avoid changing the url at every place, I will suggest define a string constant in some class and instead of using hard coded string in request mapping use that constant every where.
In future if u want tp\o change the url, simple update the constant value at one place

final String constUrl = "/myurl";

@RequestMapping(value=constUrl)

you can make the constant static, if defining in another class

Comment: yes, im doing this approach for the method request mapping but i want the extraction of this value from the super class, so it will be available for all the controllers that extends that class.

Comment: I will recommend same approach for class level request mapping as well. If you want to make that constant restricted, you can make it protected.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to stick with this approach. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The value of the annotation can be read programmatically:

```
@RequestMapping("/endpoints")
public ResponseEntity<String> getPath() {
    String path = getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(path, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the path, you should pass the Request i.e. HttpServletRequest as a parameter to your handler method.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/getThisString"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handlerMethod (Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {             
   String getThatString = request.getServletPath(); 
   ....
}
```

Reference:

- [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Comment: *@RequestMapping is only available to methods and not classes* That's not true, this annotation also works on classes. Quoting the docs: *Annotation for mapping web requests onto specific handler classes and/or handler methods.*

Comment: First line of java docs...RequestMapping Annotation for mapping web requests onto specific handler classes and/or handler methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if an URI pattern `“/getThisString”` is requested, it will map to this `MyController`, and handle the request with method where `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` is declared.

You can refer this tutorial [@RequestMapping example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/)

Hope it helps.